# Setting up Heroku to the @ record of a custom domain

Tags: heroku

I am setting up a custom domain name to my Heroku application. I setup the CNAME linking to my application, so `www.MYDOMAIN.COM` works. However, I cannot setup a CNAME record of `@`, which is `MYDOMAIN.COM`, to my application.

The DNS provider we are using is GoDaddy, which is reporting that it is an invalid record.

How does one do this for the "root domain" name?

Thanks!